# How to write a regular expression to search such string?

Tags: python, regex

```
_ntes_stocksearch_callback([{"type":"SZ","symbol":"000001","name":"a","spell":"PAYH"},{"type":"SH","symbol":"000001","name":"b","spell":"SZZS"},{"type":"FN","symbol":"000001","name":"c","spell":"HXCZHH"}])
```

How to write a regular expression pattern to get result like this:

```
{"type":"SZ","symbol":"000001","name":"a","spell":"PAYH"},
{"type":"SH","symbol":"000001","name":"b","spell":"SZZS"},
{"type":"FN","symbol":"000001","name":"c","spell":"HXCZHH"}
```

UPDATE:

I scrap something from an url and I want to make the output can be handled with function json.loads(),so what should I do?

```
import urllib2
convert_url = "http://quotes.money.163.com/stocksearch/json.do?type=&count=10&word=000001"
req = urllib2.Request(convert_url)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
html = html.decode("gbk").encode("utf-8")
print html
```

Comment: I am sorry, but Why do we need regular expression here?

Comment: @thefourtheye Because its type is str in python.I want to convert it to a dict.

Comment: Your input and output there are the same. It's hard to figure out what you want. We're going to need to see actual examples, as well as what you are trying. Basically we need more elaboration.

Comment: Do you've nested dictionaries as well?

Comment: @DanielB I update my question.Can you have a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the API is returning a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response.

So, first you'll have to "unwrap" or "convert" the format into normal json. We'll use the `callback` parameter of the url to set the JSONP function to a fixed name

```
# Setthe callback name to "n"
convert_url = "http://quotes.money.163.com/stocksearch/json.do?type=&count=10&word=000001&callback=n"
```

Then we can remove the JSONP to be left with the JSON, which can be easily parsed

```
import json

def loads_jsonp(jsonp, callback_name):
    jsonp = jsonp.strip()
    if jsonp.startswith(callback_name + '(') and jsonp.endswith(')'):
        # remove the leading "callback(" and trailing ")", then parse the json
        return json.loads(jsonp[len(callback_name) + 1:-1])
    raise ValueError.new("Callback names do not match, or invalid JSONP format")
```

Then we can apply that to our data:

```
# `jsonp_data` variable contains the body of the response
my_data = loads_jsonp(jsonp_data, "n")
```

As an alternative, you can check if the API is able to return regular JSON responses, in which case we can skip all these skips and just use `json.loads` directly.

Comment: Your solution looks much better than mine, *^*. I deleted mine, which is exactly the same as @DSM has given

Comment: @DanielB Thanks,it works.But the function len() lost the right parenthesis.

Comment: @cruelcage ah, yea. Fixed :)